# How to use conditionals in React with CssModules

Tags: reactjs, css-modules

I'm trying to use a conditional fontWeight but the same others properties in CSS.

I want to use cssmodules so I don't have all that code for each Tab.

This is my code:

```
<Tab style={{textTransform: 'none' , fontWeight: (tabValue === 0) ? 'bold' : 'normal'}} label="Updates" />
<Tab style={{textTransform: 'none' , fontWeight: (tabValue === 0) ? 'bold' : 'normal'}} label="Authorize" />
<Tab style={{textTransform: 'none' , fontWeight: (tabValue === 0) ? 'bold' : 'normal'}} label="Historical" />
```

Can I do this using ifs inside css.modules classes?

PD: Plus I want to use my constants colors in my .module.css file, is this possible?

```
import { COLORS } from '../../services/Constants';
```

Answer (score 0):

For conditionals dependant on JS, I prefer to create two classes, in this case it would be:

```
.text_bold{
  font-weight: bold;
}
.text_normal{
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

And then in your code use className preferred for certain component:

```
import * as importedClasses from './yourCss.module.css'; //Somewhere on top
<Tab className={tabValue === 0 ? importedClasses.font_bold : importedClasses.font_normal} label="Updates" />
```

Also for multiple classNames:

```
const fontClass = tabValue === 0 ? importedClasses.font_bold : importedClasses.font_normal;
<Tab className={`${fontClass} ${importedClasses.otherClass}`} label="Updates" />
```

For your PS it would be a lot easier for you if you will go with SASS/SCSS instead of CSS.

In SCSS you could import .scss files into other .scss files and use variables as simple as:

```
$yourVar: #000000;
.yourClass {
  color: $yourVar;
}
```